# How to detect sub menu click in pop up menu in android?

Tags: android, menu, popupmenu

Facing Click listener issue of Sub Menu of a Pop Up Menu in Android

Answer (score 0):

```
 Menu menu = popupMenu.getMenu();
                popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new, menu);

                SubMenu subMenu = popupMenu.getMenu().findItem(R.id.m_area).getSubMenu();


                for (int i = 0; i < subMenu.size(); i++) {
                    subMenu.getItem(i).setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onMenuItemClick(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                                case R.id.1:
                                    Toast.makeText(context, " Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;
                                case R.id.remove:
                                    Toast.makeText(context, "Remove", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    break;}

                            return true;


                        }
                    });
```